# How do I replace multiple lines near regex characters?

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, perl

Here is a portion of my source file, called "mysqld":

```
exit $r
    ;;
  'bootstrap')
      if test "$_use_whatever" == 1 ; then
        log_failure_msg "Please use galera_new_cluster to start the mariadb service with --wsrep-new-cluster"
        exit 1
      fi
      # Bootstrap the cluster, start the first node
      # that initiate the cluster
      echo $echo_n "Bootstrapping the cluster.. "
      $0 start $other_args --wsrep-new-cluster
      exit $?
      ;;
  *)
      # usage
      basename=`basename "$0"`
```

I want to replace everything within the "bootstrap" section (i.e., from >>'boostrap') ... *)<<, not inclusive) with "{NEW_BOOTSTRAP_CODE}".  So, I want it to become:

```
exit $r
    ;;
  'bootstrap')
     {NEW_BOOTSTRAP_CODE}
  *)
      # usage
      basename=`basename "$0"`
```

I've tried all kinds of sed and perl regexes, but it seems I keep getting hung up on the single quotes or parenthesis.  Here is my best failed attempt:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/\'bootstrap\'\)/.+\*\)/{BOOTSTRAP_CODE}/g' /etc/init.d/mysqld
```

It's for a raspberry pi, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Try `perl -i -0777 -pe 's/'\''bootstrap'\''\)/.+\*\)/{BOOTSTRAP_CODE}/g' /etc/init.d/mysqld`, the escaped single quote `\'` is only supported outside the single quotes (if at all).

Comment: What's `{NEW_BOOTSTRAP_CODE}` ? A multi-line string saved into a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "/^[[:blank:]]*'bootstrap')/,/^[[:blank:]]*\*)/c \\
  'bootstrap')\\
    {NEW_BOOTSTRAP_CODE}\\
  *)" script.sh
```

This applies the `sed` *change* command (`c`) to the range of lines in `script.sh` from `/^[[:blank:]]*'bootstrap')/` to `/^[[:blank:]]*\*)`. It replaces those lines with

```
  'bootstrap')
     {NEW_BOOTSTRAP_CODE}
  *)
```